# Route to corresponding exception handler in RestControllerAdvice according to header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We develop an API which services for different departments. But unfortunately, The format of error response body for 4xx or 5xx is not under our control but needs to follow these departments.

Fortunately, the requests from different departments have different `sourceid` http header.

Based on `ExceptionHandler` and `RestControllerAdvice` mechanism in Spring, is it possible to make exception be handled in correct `ExceptionHandler` according to the `sourceid` http header in the request so we can response using expected format?

Many thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything ? can u show the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Spring actually allows to select different ExceptionHandler based on headers.

However, it is possible to define one ExceptionHandler and pass `HttpServletRequest` request as method argument - and extract headers from it. And based on header value - call more specific logic